# NestJS proxy + standard route handling

Tags: nestjs, http-proxy-middleware

I use NestJS app with [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)  to proxy incoming request to the backend server.

If incoming request matches the proxy config it will handle the request and send response directly to the client without invoking standard route handling mechanism of the NestJS app.

Is there any way to process this same request with standard route handling mechanism in NestJS?

As an example what I want to achieve is to send Websocket message, SSE event, or run background task using NestJS capabilities based on response received from backend service.

Solutions I think of so far are the following:

- Create a **custom proxy middleware** where instead of `response.send()` it will be calling `next()`, but may be some other proxy-middleware solution out there that would allow this?
- Create **interceptor**, it will allow me to make a backend call and modify response based on backed response and then call next(), not sure if this will work.